# The team should be able to send an email to the Underwriter with related recommendations

Tags: dynamics-crm

1. Create a Custom workflow assembly for Audit entity
2. Look for Coverholder asscociated with Audit record. Find all Binder Sections where Expiry Date is not greater than todays date plus 6 months. Retrieve all Underwriter Contacts recorded in Binder Sections Underwriter field
3. Create an email listing the Audit Recommendations associated with the Audit where Sign Off status equals Open
4. Send email to email address associated with the Underwriter.

Please suggest how to proceed with sample code if possible

Comment: The ways to proceed with such tasks can be wide ranged. Please provide something you've tried to narrow down the approaches.

Comment: I have tried with query expression to retrieve coverholder associated with audit record.